# Printing a utf-8 character to console

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, console

I'm trying to print a utf-8 character to console.

Isn't this supposed to work?

[image]

Comment: Note the first string is `bytes` while the second isn't

Comment: `b'\xc3\x91'.decode()` should print it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former statement prints the value as `bytes` while the latter statement uses a `string` value. Changing it to `bytes` will give you the required output.

```
>>> b'\xc3\x91'.decode()
>>> 'Ñ'
```